# SWT application crashes on sun java javaws on linux

Tags: java, linux, swt, java-web-start

I wrote small application using SWT in java and it randomly crashes with no error logged. This happens only on Ubuntu 10.04 with Sun Java 1.6.xx. Application runs just fine in Open-JDK on same machine. It runs fine on windows xp and windows 7 with either Sun Java 6 or Sun Java 7. The main problem is that app runs ok if I ran it without javaws and when it crashes there is no logged anything.

I tried to add: **-Djavaplugin.logging=true** Java Runtime Environment settings, and in my home directory there are some trace files, but no error in them.

I tried to run app in terminal using: **java -verbose -wait wnclient.jnlp** and only what I get after app crashed is:

```
Java Web Start splash screen process exiting .....
Error encountered while invoking Java Web Start (execv) 
/usr/lib/jvm/jre1.6.0_33/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

I tried few version of swt and behaviour is almost the same no matter what version of swt I use or what Sun Java I use on linux.

Since there is no error I don't know what piece of code to post.

If anyone has any suggestion what can I trace to hunt down this error, I'll be very thankful.

**EDIT1:**

```
tihomir@pila:~$ ls -l /usr/lib/jvm/
total 20824
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     4096 2010-05-30 10:58 java-1.5.0-gcj-4.4
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       14 2010-05-15 18:03 java-1.6.0-openjdk -> java-6-openjdk
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root     4096 2012-09-04 19:56 java-6-openjdk
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       19 2011-08-14 09:36 java-6-sun -> java-6-sun-1.6.0.26
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root     4096 2010-12-04 11:42 java-6-sun-1.6.0.20
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root     4096 2012-01-08 19:53 java-6-sun-1.6.0.26
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root     4096 2012-08-21 18:47 jre1.6.0_33
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 21300793 2012-08-21 18:46 jre-6u33-linux-x64.bin

tihomir@pila:~$ ls -l /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.6.0_33/bin/java
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 50794 2012-06-22 01:59 /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.6.0_33/bin/java
```

Comment: Did you check if `/usr/lib/jvm/jre1.6.0_33/bin/java` really exists?

Comment: As you can see from question update that file exists.

Comment: Can you run: `/usr/lib/jvm/jre1.6.0_33/bin/java -version`?

Comment: @Baz: java version "1.6.0_33"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_33-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.8-b03, mixed mode)

Comment: If the JVM is crashing, there should be an hs_err_pid*.log file around somewhere - this will give you information about what crashed, but it will be from the JVM's internal native code.

Comment: @DietCokeOfEvil, Thank you for your suggestion. I'll check it this evening and post back the result.